# Receiving invalid left hand side of assignment error where comparison is not appropriate

Tags: octave

```
for [1:length(Vector)]
    Unique = unique(Vector)
    if any(ismember(Vector(i),Unique))
      v=Vector(i)
      Vector(i)=[]
      Unique = Unique(~ismember(v,Unique))
    endif
endfor
```

Here I am writing code, in octave, to remove all elements of Vector that aren't duplicates, leaving one less copy of each duplicate element in Vector. I am receiving error in line 2, where Unique is defined. The error is 'invalid left hand side of assignment error' which, after googling, is commonly due to use of assignment instead of comparison. However, comparison is not appropriate here.
Please can someone help me.

Comment: Is that the actual code that generated the error that you report?  The `for` statement is not correct; I think it should be `for i = [1:length(Vector)]`.  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I second the comment above, the code you provided does not work and does not return the error code you are looking for. In addition, I am not sure I understood your task: do you want to remove duplicate elements or elements which are _not_ duplicates?